# htaccess 404 page for specific subdirectory only (static html pages)

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-404, subdirectory

Stuck again with htaccess. How can I add a 404 page to a specific subdirectory?

In my case the 404 page should only affect the "**staging**" subdirectory (and the directories inside of staging) but not the root or any other subdirectories placed in root.

http://example.com/**staging**

The code which is in my .htaccess file for the directory "staging":

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]

Options -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^arbeiten/$ /staging/arbeiten/alle [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^journal/$ /staging/journal/journal-alle [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /staging/404.html
```

Using the code above (and many others) results in a Internal Server Error.

Comment: What does your error log say?

Comment: There is nothing to be found regarding my 500 Internal Server Error. At least not in the error log placed in root.

Comment: Unfortunately, it makes no difference - still getting an 500 Internal Server Error.

Comment: Is `/staging/arbeiten/` an existing directory and `/staging/arbeiten/alle` an existing file?

Comment: Yes, the directory and the file do exist.

Answer (score 0):

**Update #1** to my initial question.
In general, the code/answer provided to add a 404 not found page to a specific sub directory works:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /staging/404.html
```

The reason why it still does not work is because there must be some error in the overall .htaccess setup related to the code **remove .html** extension and/or **redirect to a page in a folder**.

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
RewriteRule ^arbeiten/$ /staging/arbeiten/alle [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^journal/$ /staging/journal/journal-alle [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /at/404.html
```

I will continue to further investigate the setup in my .htaccess.

**Update #2**
Using the .htaccess script below allows to remove .html extensions, redirect pages to a specific page within a directory and basically a working 404 not found page within a specific sub directory on a Hostgator cPanel grid hosting (apache).

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]

RewriteRule ^arbeiten/$ /staging/arbeiten/alle [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^journal/$ /staging/journal/journal-alle [R=301,L]
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/staging/404
```

Remaining 404 problem:

- http://example.com/staging/blabla (404 works)
- http://example.com/staging/folder/blala (404 works)
- http://example.com/staging/folder/project-detail-pagexxx (404 works)
- http://example.com/staging/folder/project-detail-pagexxx**/** (404 does not work)